# Hide/unhide ribbon for Microsoft RIbbon for WPF release

Tags: wpf, ms-office, ribbon, ribbon-control

MS officially released MS Ribbon for WPF. This release doesn't support theming, it comes with a default blue theme, Office 2010 look&feel. Office 2010 has a button that allows users to hide/unhide the ribbon, but the released version of ribbon doesn't has one. Is it implemented ? How can I add one?

Comment: ...and one possible answer is: "because MS Ribbon for WPF tends to look like the ribbon from MS Paint and WordPad rather than the one from Office 2010" And the ribbon from Paint and WordPad doesn't have hide/unhide option.

Comment: There's probably a way to add one, but you can doubleclick a tab in the ribbon to "minimize" the ribbon.  Well, at least in Paint.  Haven't tried it on the new ribbon yet...

Answer (score 0):

Can you doubleclick a tab to minimize the ribbon in the new release?

Kinda hidden, but been that way since office 2007, and appears to work in Windows 7 paint, etc.

Comment: It works in the new release too. Anyway I think it's really really really hidden. I've never think about it. This feature is a "hidden feature", so it doesn't exist, even if it is there, it is working. Awful.

Answer (score 0):

When I right click on the ribbon, I get the option to **Minimize the Ribbon**, which mostly hides the ribbon. Is that what you're talking about? Here's a [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/sNX89VJ6i6Q) to demonstrate. I'm using the latest Ribbon release.